# Putty permanently untick GSSAPI auth

Tags: shell, putty

I'm trying to access my server via SSH using Putty but I need to untick GSSAPI auth.
Is there a way to permanently un-tick 'Attempt GSSAPI authentication (SSH-2 only)' in Putty?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you start up Putty, you can save the session with the GSAAPI turn off. Once you start up Putty, just select the session and go from there.